# JavaFx maven, MySql, Hibernate,JPA desktop app: doesnt save yet no error or logs

Tags: mysql, hibernate, javafx

I am creating a simple CRUD JavaFX desktop application but it cant save any records and doesn't throw errors or any logs.
 
Using Hibernate 4.3.8, Netbeans 8.0.2, Java 8. 
Generated POJO in Netbeans ***See code snippets*** 
**HibernateUtil**

```
private static EntityManager entityManager; 
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if (entityManager == null) {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
            entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        }
        return entityManager;
    }
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
    @Configurable
    public class UsersService implements IServiceInterface<Users> {
    @Override
    public Users save(Users entity) {
        return usersDAO.save(entity);
    }
```

**UserController**

```
@Controller
    public class UserCtrl implements Initializable {
    private final IServiceInterface userService = new UsersService();
     public void addUser(Users user) {
        userService.save(user);
    }
    }
```

**ViewUsers**

```
public class ViewUsers {
    @FXML
    private TextField username;
    @FXML
    private TextField password;

     public void addUser(ActionEvent event) {
        Users user = new Users();
        user.setUserName(username.getText());
        user.setUserPass(password.getText());
        userCtrl.addUser(user);
    }
    }
```

**View.fxml**

```
<GridPane fx:controller="com.users.view.users" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10"
    styleClass="root">
    <TextField fx:id="username" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <PasswordField fx:id="password" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <Button text="Sign In" onAction="#addUser"/>
    </GridPane>
```

**UPDATE** I am using GenericDao

```
final EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
     @Override
    public T save(T entity) { 
            final T savedEntity = em.merge(entity);
            return savedEntity; 
    }
```

Comment: How do you inject the EntityManager into the UsersService instance?
What kind of annotations are you using in the UsersService class? Spring?

Comment: I have updated the issue. I am using GenericDao

Comment: Can you check your `fx:controller` attribute in the View.fxml file? What you have there looks wrong. (It should be `some.package.ViewUsers`.) And then how are you getting the reference to `userCtrl` in the controller? (Also, you still haven't answered the question from @Puce)

Comment: `@Service("userService")
@Configurable
public class UsersService implements ServiceInterface<Users> {`    <p> This is how i do it

Comment: That doesn't answer either question. In `ViewUsers`, how is `userCtrl` defined, and how is it initialized? Similarly for `usersDAO` in the `UsersService` class. Are you using Spring? Some other dependency injection framework?

Comment: Ok. Using Spring: `@Component
    public class ViewUsers {
    private final UserCtrl userCtrl = new UserCtrl();` UserCtrl
 
 `@Component
    public class UserCtrl implements Initializable { 
 @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userService")
    private IServiceInterface userService; @Autowired`   UserDao: 
    `private UserDAO usersDAO;`

Comment: Please edit your question and include the additional code. You are instantiating your `UserCtrl` class yourself in `ViewUsers`, instead of getting it from the Spring bean factory. Since it isn't a spring-managed bean, none of its dependencies are going to be injected by Spring. In particular, it looks like `userService` and `usersDAO` will not be initialized. I'm not sure why you're not seeing `NullPointerException`s though...